# How to use like in pagination in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

> I am getting Value of $search but not get desired output please help me find out what is wrong in my code. Thanks in advance.

```
    $users = array();
        $users = $this->paginate = array(
           'OR' => array(
              array('User.first_name LIKE' => '%$search%'),
              array('User.last_name LIKE' => '%$search%'),
              array('User.email LIKE' => '%$search%')
           ),
           'limit' => 1
        );
        $users = $this->paginate('User');
        echo '<pre>';print_r($users);die;
        $this->set('users', $users);
```

Comment: Why do you think the "number of comparisons" affects performance? There is literally nothing here that will cause any performance issue at all.

Comment: this kind of performance optimizations is a complete waste of time. You will save 5 milliseconds at most but waste hours of yours.

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: I am using 1.3 cakephp version

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if the numer is == 1, use if forloop first.

```
{%if forloop.first %}
    <tr> your new print </tr>
{% else %}
   <tr> your reprint </tr>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: can you sort it ? :)

Comment: Could you be more specific ?